# node.js is looking for a module even though the code is fed through STDIN

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I want to do some tests on canvas purely in node.js.

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "anthony@work",
  "dependencies": {
    "canvas": "^1.6.7",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "jsdom": "^11.3.0"
  }
}
```

This is my .babelrc

```
{
 "presets": ["env", "stage-0"]
}
```

This is my test javascript (`a.js`)

```
const { jsdom } = require('jsdom');

// main
jsdom();


console.log('done')
```

All these files are located in a directory `/work`

When I run the script by piping the babel output into nodejs via STDIN,

```
 npx babel a.js | nodejs -- -
```

I get this error:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/work/-'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:800:14)
```

What causes this error? It seems like node is looking for a `work` module. How can I fix this error?

Version information:

Node.js: v6.11.5
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)

Comment: Should that not be `npx babel-node a.js`? There's a bit more in the packaging than simply piping through

Comment: If I use `babel-node` I got a different error message: `jsdom is not a function`. Does `babel-node` know how to use `node_modules`?

Comment: Yep. But for that matter, should that not be `import { jsdom } from 'jsdom';` or `const jsdom = require('jsdom')` which is the node form. Frankly given the latter it would be `import jsdom from 'jsdom'`. You seem confused on destructuring and `import` assignments here. Unless there is an "export" of `jsdom` then "my" first example is wrong, and "yours" is definitely wrong.

Comment: You're right. I should switch to `import ... from ...` syntax too in the code

Comment: Please turn your comment into an answer and I will upvote and accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use `babel-node` instead of `babel`

```
npx babel-node a.js
```